# error: Ambiguous getter for Field You can @Ignore the ones that you don't want to match

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have the following code structure:

```
interface Watchable {
    fun show: Show
}

@Entity
@Parcelize
data class TopRatedShow(
    @Embedded
    val show: Show,

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "topRatedShowId") val id: Int = show.id
) : Parcelable, Watchable {

    override fun show(): Show {
        return show
    }
}
```

But my code wont compile and throw:

```
 error: Ambiguous getter for Field(element=show, name=show, type=com.zk.***.Show,
 affinity=null, collate=null, columnName=show, defaultValue=null, parent=null, 
 indexed=false, nonNull=true).
 All of the following match: show, getShow.
 You can @Ignore the ones that you don't want to match.

 private final com.zk.***.Show show = null;
```

It seems that combining @Embedded with implementing the interface is causing the issue but I don't fully understand what seems to be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your class, function signature, as well as val name is show, room is having problem on which one to choose.

```
    interface Watchable {
        fun show: Show
    }

    @Entity
    @Parcelize
    data class TopRatedShow(
        @Embedded
        val myshow: Show,
    
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        @ColumnInfo(name = "topRatedShowId") val id: Int = myshow.id
    ) : Parcelable, Watchable {
    
        override fun show(): Show {
            return myshow
        }
    }
```

Either you can change the val name or you can tell room which one to ignore using @Ignore